# java убрать из консоли детализацию

Tags: java, консоль

Добрый день
Понимаю что вопрос глупый, но все же.
При запуске jar пакета (своего), в консоль выводится ненужная информация:

```
Trying to load 64-bit library on WINDOWS 7
Java properties: 
 - Java vendor URL: HTTP://JAVA.ORACLE.COM/
 - Java VM name: JAVA HOTSPOT(TM) 64-BIT SERVER VM
 - Java VM vendor: ORACLE CORPORATION
 - Java vendor: ORACLE CORPORATION
 - Java runtime name: JAVA(TM) SE RUNTIME ENVIRONMENT
```

Также при запуске из netBeans выводятся эти же строки. 
Как их можно убрать, т.к. приложение должно считывать результат работы java

Comment: Как вы его запускаете?

Comment: Из консоли: java -jar File.jar
Как запускает NetBeans не знаю. Это где-то в самой яве настраивается?

Comment: Может быть это запрограммировано у вас в самом запускаемом классе? Либо это выводится при неудачной попытке загрузить какие-то Windows API библиотеки. Java сама ничего такого обычно не выводит.  Попробуйте её переустановить.

Comment: Нет. Выводится через System.out.println. Выводится только мое, откуда берется это, не знаю. Ладно бы NetBeans выводил, так и через консоль тоже самое

Comment: Я так понимаю проблема с 64-битной jdk. Попробую переустановить, а потом 32 битную поставить

Comment: Проблема где-то в настройках jvm

Comment: Если проблема решена, напишите ответ на свой вопрос. Вдруг кому-то ещё пригодится.